# Using LaTex "~" symbol in Python using LaTeX

Tags: latex, tilde

Please see the piece of the code I am using to produce an image. At the end, I want to write a text withing the image. There, i want to use "~" symbol using TeX rendering set through rc parameters. But, when I run the code, it doesn't even print the "tilde" symbol. Any idea, how can I incorporate this? Thanks.

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font',size=size_axislabels,**{'family':'serif','serif':['Times'],'weight' : 'bold'})
bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="Square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="0.5", lw=3)    
........
........
ax.text(90, 41, r"Distance: $~$ 500 pc", ha="center", va="center", size=20,transform=ax.get_transform('galactic'),
        bbox=bbox_props)
```

Comment: use $\sim$ for the tilde symbol in latex math mode. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86377/how-can-i-write-tilde-in-math-mode/86379

Comment: Thank you @Johann. It worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To post my comment as an answer:

The problem ist that you are not using the correct latex command for a tilde. In math mode, you can use `$\sim$` to write a tilde.

Comment: That helps, @Johann. Thanks!